# Eulerwalk around Forest tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

Is there a clever way to draw an Eulerian walk around a tree? My current solution is quite clumsy...

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{moloch}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
 \begin{forest}
   [-
     [$\div$, tikz+={
         \draw [-Latex, mLightBrown, thick, rounded corners] 
           (-.5,0) to (-1.6,-1) 
               to (-2.5,-2.3)
               to (-3.1,-4.5)
               to (-3.1,-4.9)
               to (-2.5,-4.9)
               to (-2.3,-4)
               to (-2.1,-4.9)
               to (-1.8,-4.9)
               to (-1.8,-4.5)
               to (-2.2,-3.3)
               to (-2,-2.7)
               to (-1.8,-3.7)
               to (-1.4,-3.7)
               to (-1.5,-2.7)
               to (-1.8,-2.2)
               to (-1.3,-1.3)
               to (-.8,-2.2)
               to (-1.5,-4.3)
               to (-1.5,-4.9)
               to (-1.1,-4.9)
               to (-.9,-4)
               to (-.7,-4.9)
               to (-.3,-4.9)
               to (-.3,-4.5)
               to (-.7,-3.3)
               to (-.5,-2.7)
               to (-.3,-3.7)
               to (0,-3.7)
               to (0,-3)
               to (-.9,-1.2)
               to (0,-.2)
               to (.9,-1.2)
               to (0.3,-3)
               to (0.3,-3.7)
               to (.8,-3.7)
               to (.9,-2.7)
               to (1.1,-3.5)
               to (.6,-4.9)
               to (1.2,-4.9)
               to (1.3,-4)
               to (1.4,-4.9)
               to (1.8,-4.9)
               to (1.1,-2)
               to (1.3,-1.4)
               to (1.5,-2.5)
               to (1.9,-2.5)
               to (1.9,-2)
               to (1.3,-.7)
               to (.5,0);
         }
       [$\times$
         [$+$
           [3]
           [1]
         ]
         [3]
       ]
       [$+$
         [$-$
           [9]
           [5]
         ]
         [2]
       ]
     ]
     [$+$
       [$\times$
         [3]
         [$-$
           [7]
           [4]
         ]
       ]
       [6]
     ]
   ]
 \end{forest}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and yields the following:

[image: eulerian walk around tree screenshot]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work for any tree where every node has either zero or two children. It could be adapted for other cases, but I did not account for those here.

I would have liked to have defined some kind of `step` rather than doing it mechanically, but I'm not sure how to do something similar to `tree`, since `tree` and friends are defined in terms of internal commands.

The basic strategy is to define a custom `toks` register, `outer walk`, which we use to accumulate parts of the `path` we want to draw. We basically draw around the tree by taking advantage of the regularities in its structure: we know the order in which `forest` processes nodes in step `tree` and so we add bits to the path (1) for each node and (2) for each leaf. In the latter case, we figure out whether this is a first or second child, in order to add the various additions to the path in the appropriate places. We then add the final node, which we know is the root node, and feed the contents of `outer walk` to a `\path` command via `tikz+`.

Anyway, the upshot is that `euler` is a mechanical style and not clever at all, but it does let you write

```
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    math content,
  },
  euler,
  [-
    [\div
      [\times
        [+
          [3]
          [1]
        ]
        [3]
      ]
      [+
        [-
          [9]
          [5]
        ]
        [2]
      ]
    ]
    [+
      [\times
        [3]
        [-
          [7]
          [4]
        ]
      ]
      [6]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

to produce

[image: euler style applied to tree]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/712007/ addaswyd o gwestiwn Arne: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/711954/
\begin{document}
\forestset{
  declare toks register={outer walk},
  outer walk={},
  euler/.style={
    before drawing tree={
      for tree={
        outer walk+/.process={Ow{name}{(##1.west) -- }},
        if={>On={n children}{0}}{
          outer walk+/.process={Ow{name}{(##1.south west) -- (##1.south east) -- (##1.east) -- }},
          if n=2{
            Nodewalk={}{while={> On= On> & {n}{2} {level}{1} }{u}}{outer walk+/.process={Ow{name}{(##1.east) -- }}},
            if n=1{
              outer walk+/.process={Ow{!u.name}{(##1.south)  --  }},
            }{},
          }{
            outer walk+/.process={Ow{!u.name}{(##1.south) -- }},
          },
        } {}
      },
      outer walk+/.process={Ow{name}{(##1.east)}},
      typeout/.register=outer walk,
      tikz+={
        \path [draw=brown!50!orange,-Latex,rounded corners] \foresteregister{outer walk};
      },
    },
  },
}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    math content,
  },
  euler,
  [-
    [\div
      [\times
        [+
          [3]
          [1]
        ]
        [3]
      ]
      [+
        [-
          [9]
          [5]
        ]
        [2]
      ]
    ]
    [+
      [\times
        [3]
        [-
          [7]
          [4]
        ]
      ]
      [6]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

This isn't automated, but you can use the `forest` node internal id (accessible with `\forestoption{id}` to give each node a `name`. Then use those names to draw a path that fits the nodes better.

I added a macro `\leaf` to draw around the bottoms of the leaves and keep the code a bit cleaner.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{euler/.style={thick, orange, rounded corners, -Latex}}
\newcommand{\leaf}[1]{(N-#1.north west)--(N-#1.south west)--(N-#1.south east)--(N-#1.north east)}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={math content, name=N-\forestoption{id}}
[-[\div[\times[+[3][1]][3]][+[-[9][5]][2]]][+[\times[3][-[7][4]]][6]]]
\draw[euler] (N-2.west)--(N-3.west)--(N-4.west)--(N-5.west)--\leaf{6}
    --(N-5.south)--\leaf{7}--(N-5.east)--(N-4.south)--\leaf{8}
    --(N-4.east)--(N-3.south)--(N-9.west)--(N-10.west)--\leaf{11}
    --(N-10.south)--\leaf{12}--(N-10.east)--(N-9.south)--\leaf{13}
    --(N-9.east)--(N-3.east)--(N-2.south)--(N-14.west)--(N-15.west)--\leaf{16}
    --(N-15.south)--(N-17.west)--\leaf{18}--(N-17.south)--\leaf{19}
    --(N-17.east)--(N-15.east)--(N-14.south)--\leaf{20}--(N-14.east)--(N-2.east);
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Just so you can see how the internal numbering of nodes works, here is each node with its contents replaced by its internal id.

[image]

To get this image, replace the `for tree` with this code:

```
for tree={math content, name=N-\forestoption{id}, delay={content=\forestoption{id}}}
```